# Attempted to load class "COM" from namespace -Symfony2

Tags: php, class, symfony, ms-access

I am developing a web using symfony2 framework. In this web the users upload file(.mdb). The web read the file and if the information is correct it pass to database.(This is the idea)

The problem is that i try to used "COM class of PHP". First i think that i forget too put the extension "extension=php_com_dotnet.dll" but no.

Hay use this code to read de mdb

```
    $count =0;
    $db_path = $path;
    $constr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" . $db_path . ";";
    $odbc_con = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
    $odbc_con -> open($constr);
```

But Symfony say me

Attempted to load class "COM" from namespace "PintxoNosti\MyTellBundle\Controller" in C:\Symfony\WebD\src\PintxoNosti\MyTellBundle\Controller\PintxoController.php line 62. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

someone know the solution?
 Or maybe have some idea to read mdb in symfony2

Thanks.

Comment: Use `\Com`. When you are using namespaces a class name without any kind of `use` statement or one that isn't full qualified is classed as in the same namespace as the current class, so in this case `PintxoNosti\MyTellBundle\Controller`. If you prefix your class with a `\` you are locating it in the global namespace rather than the local.

Comment: Cool.. Just to correct 'If you prefix your class with a ` \ ` you are locating it in the global namespace rather than the local.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Symfony you use namespaces. imagine that you want to make an instance of COM into a controller, lets say MyController. Your controller PHP file will begin with this rule:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
```

Now if you make an instance of the PHP COM class PHP will search this class into the AppBundle\Controller namespace, where it of course couldn't be found because it is in the **global namespace**.

So you have to add a \ before COM to indicate that this class can be found in the global namespace:

```
$odbc_con = new \COM("ADODB.Connection");
```

Comment: someone know how to define the path? This is my current problem   <b>Source:</b> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers<br/><b>Description:</b> [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] '(desconocido)' no es una ruta de acceso v�lid                        and i use   $constr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" ."../../web/uploads/imgPintxos/". $db_path . ";";